# Adding Object to ArrayList Causes Object's Property to Convert Type

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm working with Exchange Server 2013 Distribution Groups and an ArrayList.

```
$groups = @()
$groups += Get-DistributionGroup "groupName"
foreach($group in $groups)
...
```

I'm attempting to extract the `$group.ManagedBy` property, which is an `ADMultiValuedProperty`, however within my script, `ManagedBy` is being converted into an ArrayList, and I lose the properties of `ManagedBy` because of it (e.g. `$group.ManagedBy.Name` is blank when there should be value). Why would this type conversion happen?

Comment: Are you using a remote management session on one of your Exchange servers, or an actual EMS shell?

Comment: Though ISE via remote session, although taking place on the Exchange server directly. Ideally, I would like this to work with remote sessions if possible.

Comment: Remote sessions produce deserialized objects, which results in a loss of fidelity.  There's no fix for it that I'm aware of, you just have to work around it.

Comment: At the database layer, `managedBy` is a single-valued string (referering to the DN of the principal who manages the group). What makes you assume that it's multi-valued?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - Get-DistributionGroup returns a different object type than Get-ADGroup, and Get-Member on one of those objects does show it to be multivalued property.

Comment: @mjolinor can you please make your comment regarding the deserialization an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: Done. Added some additional comments on serialization/deserialization in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is a consequence of using the remote management sessions.  Objects returned from a remote session go through a serialization/deserialization process, and you're left with a deserialized object. Serialization only maintains fidelity to a limited depth, and as a result you may lose some properties of objects nested in the properties of the base object. You will also lose the object methods.

When you serialize and deserialize objects manually (using export/import-clixml) you can specify the fidelity depth to maintain, but as far as I know this is fixed for the serialization process that remoting uses, and there is no way to change it.  You just have to learn to expect it and code around it.